# Possible to show n and all positive n-x decrements of number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry for what feels like a very basic question, but I'm really puzzled over if or how it's possible to do this in a spreadsheet formula.

If I have some cell containing a number N, I'd like to be able to show another cell that displays a list of N and every positive decrement of N-X, for example:

If cell A1 is 17, Cell A2 should be 17, 12, 7, 2 if X=5

where N is arbitrarily large.

I'm trying to avoid the use of macros, or this would be trivial in a loop.

Comment: @pnuts with `TEXTJOIN` you do not need helper cells. I'm sure you simply missed the "or" between "this" and "if" ;D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the newest Excel (2016 or online) and `A1` for `n` and `B1` for `x` you can use

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,A1-(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(A1/B1,0)))-1)*B1)
```

> This is an Arrayformula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Cell A1 = N
- Cell B1 = x
- Cell A2 and copied down is this formula: `=A1-B$1`

That will give you the following results (using values from your given sample data in your original post):

```
     A    B
1    17   5
2    12
3     7
4     2
5    -3
```

If you only want positive values shown, use this formula in cell A2 instead and copy down:

`=IF(A1-B$1<0,"",A1-B$1)`

Comment: This isn't quite what I mean. I'm looking for a way to express "17, 12, 7, 2" in a single cell when the referenced values are "17" and "5"

Comment: @T.J.Compton That would require VBA, and is not recommended.  Excel is best utilized over multiple cells for multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom function with VBA like this:

```
Function test(n, x)
Dim str As String
str = n
    Do While n - x > 0
    str = str & ", " & n - x
    n = n - x
    Loop
test = str
End Function
```

Then in your cell:

```
=test(A1, B1)
```